# Final Fantasy XIII Paradigm shifts

Tags: final-fantasy-13

Whenever I shift paradigms in Final Fantasy XIII, sometimes I get the animation for each individual character switching paradigms, and sometimes I get the animation for all three switching at the same time which is tremendously faster.

I think I get the individual animations while I'm currently attacking an enemy, but I'm not sure if that is the reason.

How do I consistently get the animation where everyone switches paradigms at the same time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first time you shift in a battle, you get the full animation where each character changes one at a time.  All future shifts in that fight are the abbreviated version.

I believe there are a handful of times where you can skip the full-length animation on the first transition, such as during certain jump attacks, but then you might get the full animation on the next transition instead.

Comment: Hm, I will test this out when I get home from work.

Comment: I say this because I swear I've had the individual transitions after the first transition

Comment: The first half of my answer I'm more sure about because I used to intentionally shift early so I could quickly shift at key moments on more difficult fights.  Are you on PC or console?

Comment: I am on Xbox 360

Comment: Wow you're right. The first one does the individual animations and anything after that was the faster one